# How to delete mvc webgrid row by calling ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

in my mvc razor view, I have a partial view with webgrid data, I need to add an actionlink to delete that row data, This is what I did:
This is javascript function:
    
        function delMeal(pid) {

```
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete Meal: " + pid)) {
            var data = { 'MealID': pid }
            $.post('/Travel/DeleteMeal', data,
            function (data) {
                if (data == true)
                    location = location.href;
                else
                    alert("Could not delete");
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is controller method:

```
public JsonResult DeleteMeal(Int32 productId)
    {  
        //NWDataContext db = new NWDataContext();
        Meal product = db.Meals.Where(x => x.MealID == productId).FirstOrDefault();
        db.Meals.Remove(product);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is row with delete function call on webgrid
     @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteMeal", "Travel", new { onclick = "delMeal("+item.MealID+")"})

The above code in action link does not work, since I added method ("DeleteMeal") in it, but if I remove that method, the javascript function is called, but method("DeleteMeal") does not call. 
can anybody help me out to make above the codes in @Html.ActionLink working? thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Travel/DeleteMeal'
        data: {
            productId:pid
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) {
            if(!json.error) 
            $("#grid").load('Url which Send data to This grid');
        }
        error: errorFunc
});
```

Then see your DeleteMeal action is called or not updated.

Comment: I think the codes in razor view must be changed, do you know how to change it?

Comment: I tried your codes, I got "Success" popup and I can see the record has been deleted from SQL table, but my page redircted to  new site which is not existed: Requested URL: /Travel/DeleteMeal with "The resource cannot be found. ", It make scence because I do not DeleteMeal view at all, but it is still direct to it. and the URL is: "http://localhost:57166/Travel/DeleteMeal?Length=6", after deletion, I want to current page (razor view) is still stay there, but the webgrid which containts the deleted record will be refreshed with the rows after deletion. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I think the code in razor view should be changed, please let me know how to make it working,   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteMeal", "Travel", new { onclick = "delMeal("+item.MealID+")"})

Comment: since the controller method is called by ajax code, so I think I should remove it from the ActionLink, so I tried this:@Html.ActionLink("Delete1", "", "", new { onclick = "delMeal("+item.MealID+")"}), this time, no error, but the page return to home page which is not what wanted, I want it stay on current page with refreshed webgrid which is partial view contains the updated webgrid data. any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I also changed JsonReult to ActionResult and changed return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri); or add these codes int FINtravelID = product.FINtravelID;
FINtravel fintravel = new FINtravel();
            fintravel = db.FINtravels.Find(fintravelID);
return PartialView("_MealPartial", fintravel); but no luck.

Comment: I updated my codes as you instructed, it works well. But, after deletion, the code "location.reload(true)" caused the entire page (razor view) refresh(reload), since my current page has other webgrid with many fields, so ideally if I can only refresh the webgrid (which is inside of a partial view) related the row deletion, doing that way, user will not see the entire page reload with the partial view updated. please let me know if you know how to make it working. my webgrid inside partialview using <div id="grid", can we change the Jason return in controller to partialview?

Comment: See my updated code. Provide us the Controller name and Action name which is sending data to your grid

Comment: following your instruction, keep the other codes, I updated the jquery codes as follows: success: function (jason) {
                var pathname = window.location.pathname;
                var path1 = "http://localhost:57166" +  pathname + "#tabs-2";
                    alert(path1);
                    if (!jason.error)
                        $("#grid").load('path1');
                } I can see the path is correct (http://localhost:57166/Travel/Edit/7518#tabs-2) in my alert popup, but the page always redirect to "http://localhost:57166/" , not the current Eidt view in tab2, any idea?

Comment: why you are using 'path1'?there is no need for path1. What happens when you use $('#grid).laod();